# How to return an array from SQL in VB?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to run a SQL query from VB that returns an array of all unique values (Btl) for a given day, in time ascending order.

I'm working off of someone else's code and modifying from a version that only returned a single int value each day. (e.g. '1' , but I would like it to modify it to return '1 2 3 4')

I've tried to convert the 'Btl' variable to an array like 'Btl()' but I get the error that "Value of type 'Integer()' cannot be converted to 'Integer'"

```vb
        'Get 'wherecl' table 
        Function GetBtl(ByVal tblRS As String, ByVal nday As Integer, ByVal sqlConn As 
     SqlConnection) As Integer
        ' Get the day's sample bottle
        Dim wherecl As String
        wherecl = "WHERE (DATEDIFF(d, { fn NOW() }, TmStamp) = " & nday & ")"
        Dim Q4 As String


        ' SQL cmd to get array of unique bottles each day 
        Q4 = "SELECT distinct BottleToSample FROM " & tblRS & " " &
    wherecl &
    " ORDER BY TmStamp ASC;"
        'End If

        Dim MCGQ4 As New SqlCommand(Q4, sqlConn)
        Dim Btl As Integer = MCGQ4.ExecuteScalar    'This is the bottle number
        Return Btl

    End Function
```

This version compiles, but doesn't display any results.

I would like it to deliver "1 2 3 4" for example

Comment: ExecuteScalar only returns one value, you'll have to use ExecuteReader

Comment: @RyanWilson DataAdapter is overkill. needs only a reader

Comment: @Mr.Tripodi Why is it overkill? So you can do `while DataReader.Read()` ???

Comment: Just use .Load method on DataTable. Actually, id probably just create the array from Reader and not use DT

Answer (score 2):

As an unknown (presumably) number of bottles will be read, it is a good idea to put the data into a List(Of Integer) - a List will expand its capacity automatically when items are added to it. If you actually need the data in an array, that can easily be done.

When using a connection to a database, that connection should be opened, the data read, and then the connection disposed of immediately. [SQL Server Connection Pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) makes that efficient. In the case of the code in the question, I achieved that by using the connection string from the connection. The [Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) takes care of freeing up unmanaged resources even if something goes wrong.

```
Function GetBtl(ByVal tblRS As String, ByVal nday As Integer, ByVal sqlConn As SqlConnection) As Integer()
    Dim sampleBottles As New List(Of Integer)

    ' Get the day's sample bottles
    Dim wherecl As String = "WHERE (DATEDIFF(d, { fn NOW() }, TmStamp) = " & nday & ")"
    ' SQL cmd to get array of unique bottles each day 
    Dim Q4 As String = "SELECT distinct BottleToSample FROM " & tblRS & " " & wherecl & " ORDER BY TmStamp ASC;"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(sqlConn.ConnectionString),
          MCGQ4 As New SqlCommand(Q4, conn)

        conn.Open()
        Dim rdr = MCGQ4.ExecuteReader()

        While rdr.Read()
            sampleBottles.Add(rdr.GetInt32(0))
        End While

    End Using

    Return sampleBottles.ToArray()

End Function
```

---

*Also,* I notice that there is a line `Dim Btl As Integer = MCGQ4.ExecuteScalar` in the code in the question, which indicates that Option Strict is set to "Off". That is a sub-optimal condition; it would be a good idea to use [`Option Strict On`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/1115360). It could take some effort to correct all the code with that, but it will end up removing variable type problems.